# Why Skype discloses my IP address to anybody?

Tags: network, privacy, exploit, ip, skype

Apparently there is a Skype exploit that allows people to obtain your IP address through your Skype username if you're online. The problem has existed since 2012. There exists countless websites which resolves Skype usernames into IP addresses.

So why hasn't this been fixed yet?

Comment: Only Microsoft can answer this. VoIP/video chat uses peer to peer connection (the caller/callee connects to each other directly instead of through a server) which requires a participant in a call to have each other's IP address. But there are no reasons why people not in your contacts list need to know your IP address if you only allow calls from people in your contact list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe they already have if this article is correct:
http://community.skype.com/t5/Security-Privacy-Trust-and/How-to-protect-your-IP-from-skype-resolvers/td-p/3874291

Skype uses peer-to-peer instead of traditional client/server connections to make the calls happen though. Since there's no sole middleman the data needs to know where it's going between each peer through an ip address. A traditional server can have both users connected and control the flow of information so that the IP isn't exposed to either user.

I am curious what this fix does to circumvent needing the destination IP address. Someone else could probably clarify better.

Comment: I quickly read this article, and one of the action seems to closely match @LieRyan comment: *Check "Allow direct connections to your contacts only."*. So, basically, by default anybody could establish a direct contact to you, so anybody needs access to your IP address. This procedures changes this default setting to limit direct connections to the contact list then indicates a few ways to get a new IP address.

Comment: Great answer but such a ridiculous flaw. This solution will probably never reach the poor non IT people, making them easier targets...